# Map heap memory to shared memory (Windows)

Tags: windows, memory, memory-mapped-files

Suppose I have a function which takes as an input a pointer to (process) heap memory. This function communicates with a service process on the same system, and uses shared memory to communicate (I require maximum throughput so this is the only acceptable form of IPC I can use).

Is there a way to use the already allocated heap memory as shared memory (i.e. map it to a file) without needing to reallocate a shared memory buffer of the same size? Because I will need to support memory buffers of several hundred megabytes (possibly gigabytes) and having to allocate that much memory twice sucks.

Also, allocating a small shared memory buffer and repeatedly using it is not acceptable because of latency (since I will need to synchronize the small buffer updates between the two processes several times).

I could design my function such that it requires a pointer to shared memory instead but that is putting a burden on the users of my function (since they will have to manage their shared memory themselves) and is much less flexible, as well as incurring quite a lot of overhead if not managed properly.

TL;DR: I need a way to map heap memory in such a way that another process can directly write in it without needing to go through an intermediary shared memory buffer.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.